# Changing transparency band on raster layer using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, transparency-opacity

How to change programmatically (from Python or Console QGIS) Transparency band in QGIS on the raster layer, this parameter is shown in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("rasterlayernamehere")[0]
r = layer.renderer()
print(r.alphaBand()) #None set = -1
#-1
r.setAlphaBand(1) #Set it to first band
print(r.alphaBand())
#1
layer.triggerRepaint()
```